# Displaying data from firebase into a refreshing html table using Javascript + Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

This is my first Dynamic project using javascript and firebase and I've been having trouble displaying the data into the table, I have looked at at other pages but I was unable to use these tutorials or learn from responses. What I desire is to get the data displayed and refreshed whenever a new order is detected.

My code is here and the database is available on request. Thank you in advance.

```
<body>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>




    <table id ="orders" style ="width:50%">
      <tr>
        <th>Order</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>order No.</th>
        <th>Items</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Benton Sans", "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 2em;
}

h1 {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #373fff;
}

#orders{
 border:2px solid black; 
}
th{
 border: 1px solid black;
  border-left:none;
  border-right:none;
}


</style>
<script>
var config = {
    apiKey: "*****",
    authDomain: "mycanteenapp-b0dfc.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://mycanteenapp-b0dfc.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "mycanteenapp-b0dfc",
    storageBucket: "mycanteenapp-b0dfc.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "18960278720"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

 var database = firebase.database(MyCanteen);
    database.ref(break).once('value', function(snapshot){
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            var content = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                var val = data.val();
                content +='<tr>';
                content += '<td>' + val.Order + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val.name + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val.orderNo + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val.Items + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val.Price + '</td>';
                content += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#orders').append(content);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error? Is anything happening? When you `console.log(snapshot)` does it show anything?

Comment: @RobertAKARobin the result on the html is blank and I'll check the console logs now. Nothing logs to the console

Comment: Is this your full code? Where is the `break` in `.ref(break)` coming from?

Comment: I was referring to break within my database

Comment: On the line after `database.ref(break).once('value', function(snapshot){`, try just doing a `console.log('hello')`. Does it show up in the console? If not, it means you're unable to connect to the Firebase database.

Comment: Great ill try that thank you.

Comment: its showing up nothing, but when i added another console.log command outside of the function that also didnt show up in the console. not sure whats wrong